# How To Automatic Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

i don't know how to perfectly code in javascript and i'm a little lost, i have this code, i want to make this slideshow automatic but also to make it so people can move between images freely without any problem. i can't figure out how to do this if you can help i'll be very happy, thanks for the helpers :)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

.mySlides {display: none}

img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* next button to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev{
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next, {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/ea35b10621f0083ed1534705fb0938c9bd22ffd41cb3154996f6c97aa0/background-3009949_1920.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/ea35b10621f0083ed1534705fb0938c9bd22ffd41cb3154996f6c97aa0/background-3009949_1920.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/ea35b10621f0083ed1534705fb0938c9bd22ffd41cb3154996f6c97aa0/background-3009949_1920.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ plusSlides(1) }, 3000);` where 3000 is number of milliseconds between slides

Comment: @Camille that should probably be a `setInterval`, although it depends on implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this at the end of your javascript

```
// Start Recursive function
(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  setInterval(function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000);
})();
```

> Snipplet

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

// Start Recursive function
(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  setInterval(function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000);
})();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

.mySlides {display: none}

img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* next button to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev{
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next, {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/423603/pexels-photo-423603.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/877867/pexels-photo-877867.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/614484/pexels-photo-614484.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: the auto slideshow works but when refreshing the slide show takes 3 seconds to appear if i set the time to 5 sec it take 5 sec to fully display the slideshow

Comment: I dont understand your comment. Your code display first slide show and `setInterval` will wait specified amount of time to call `plusSlides(1)`. What do you mean by refreshing? Full page refresh? Dynamic refresh?

Comment: full page refresh, when i press F5 in my browser the takes 3 sec to 
the slideshow to appear but after that it works as it should, and if i set the time to 5 sec it takes the slideshow 5 sec to appear on my browser

Comment: strange...I made a new version, try it. Btw, which browser and version do you use?

Comment: yeah now it working properly, thank you so much :), im using chrome version 66.0.3359.139

Comment: Glad to help :-)